# How to align Radio Button text in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-radiobutton

New to android.I am using radio Button in my android app

```
questionbtnD = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.optionD);
questionbtnD.setText(Html.fromHtml(dq.get(id).getOptions().get(3).toString().trim()));
```

and text coming is like [image]

`<![CDATA[ <p>    Won't compile because of line (1) – constructor can't be private </p> ]]>`

but its is not properly aligned can any body help me how to align this.

Comment: hrm, adding `android:gravity="center"` or `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to the RadioButton xml might fix it.

Comment: @Sahil, can you paste the code for you xml here? Show us what u've done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the issue in HTML I was using

which was giving one extra line due to which I was getting extra one lank Line Now I remove

Tag

```
<![CDATA[     Won't compile because of line (1) – constructor can't be private  ]]>
```

So Its working fine for me now

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea how to use the `LayoutParams`

```
  RadioGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 32, 0, 0);
        RadioButton rButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
        rButton.setText("stuff");
        rButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        rButton.setPadding(140, 0, 40, 0);
        radioGroupPair.addView(rButton);
```

This is the xml

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroupPair"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks Murat fro reply, I already used for  Layout params like wrap_Content, Margins and padding but not working for me.

Comment: @Sahil This is exactly how I used it in my code and its perfectly aligned. Maybe us some dummy text to see that the strings are not too long to fit.

Comment: If I am not using HTML Content Then Its Working fine but with Html only it is giving problem